# Exception Security Context token in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, service, token

I'm using Service WCF, and I get the following error:

> The security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed.

Client config

```
<endpoint address="http://probiz:49610/GestionOrganizacion.svc"
  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IOrganizacion"  
  contract="CarWin.ServiceContracts.Interfaces.IOrganizacion" 
  behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior"
  name="PRO_WSHttpBinding_IOrganizacion">
<identity>
  <dns value="localhost" />
</identity>
```

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IOrganizacion" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
    openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
    allowCookies="false">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
  <security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

more config:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

will enforce security on the message. If that is not needed, you might want to try  See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx) for more info.